# If a string is present in the word, make it NA in python

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a list of words like,

```
c= ('an', 'abc', 'pls')
```

and then I have a column in dataframe,

```
df['column']

another
fan
Ind
abcd
point
plsea
```

I want to check if the value in the c is present in df['column'], I want to make it NA. The output I need to get is,

```
NA
NA
Ind
NA
point
NA
```

The following are my tryings,

```
c in df['column']
False
```

Getting only for the first row. Not able to do it. Can anybody help me in doing this?

Comment: You can use `df.replace()`, have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142304/replace-string-value-in-entire-dataframe

Comment: @Jaco I tried this and I am getting errors here. also replace, just replaces the particular string. I want to change the entire string to NA

Answer (score 4):

If you join `'|'` on all the words in `c` to produce a regex pattern then you can pass this to [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and set all matches to `'NA'`:

```
In [21]:
df.loc[df['words'].str.contains('|'.join(c)),'words'] = 'NA'
df

Out[21]:
   words
0     NA
1     NA
2    Ind
3     NA
4  point
5     NA
```

Here is the output of the intermediate steps:

```
In [23]:
'|'.join(c)

Out[23]:
'an|abc|pls'

In [24]:
df['words'].str.contains('|'.join(c))

Out[24]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
Name: words, dtype: bool
```

Comment: but why should I join everything to a single word? Every word is individual entry right?

Comment: because it makes a regex pattern `word|word1|word2` so it will match on the presence on any of these words, additionally you can see that my output matches your desired output

Comment: for some reason after df['words'].str.contains('|'.join(c)) step, I am getting everything as NAs. I am doing this in my dataset

Comment: well it means that you're matching on every row which may be possible, based on your sample data and requirements this is what my code will do and is the correct behaviour as described. Unless you post your real data or mode information then it's difficult to comment further

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a pandas specific way of doing it, but just using pure python you would iterate over each value in the column and then check to see if any of the words in `c` appear in it,

```
for idx, value in enumerate(df['column']):
    if any([word in value for word in c]):
        df['column'][idx] = 'NA'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply()` with a lambda expression:

```
df['column'].apply(lambda x: 'NA' if any(s in x for s in c) else x)
```

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

c = ('an', 'abc', 'pls')
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,'another'],[3,4,'fan'],[5,6,'Ind'],[0,0,'abcd'],[1,2,'point'],[22,44,'plsea']])
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']

>>> df['C'].apply(lambda x: 'NA' if any(s in x for s in c) else x)
0       NA
1       NA
2      Ind
3       NA
4    point
5       NA
Name: C, dtype: object
```

If you want to update the original data frame:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: 'NA' if any(s in x for s in c) else x)
```

will do it.

Comment: I thought this one was perfect. But the dataframe is still returning the same values :(

Comment: I am getting the same output as input

Comment: For the edit, "argument of type 'float' is not iterable" this error is coming

Comment: Where on earth is a `float` coming from? It's not in your sample data.

Comment: @Observer: are you trying to _update_ the data frame in place?  If so see my updated answer.

Comment: I am getting something like this, "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

Comment: Do you really have a dataframe, or is it just a list? The error message says that it's a lsit. Does the example in my answer work if you copy/paste into your interpreter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dataframe `replace` function with a regular expression and `numpy.NAN`. This works a a partially replacement also gives a `NAN` value. You can then use `fillna` to fill the replaced values with `NA`:

```
df['column']=df['column'].replace('|'.join(c),np.NAN,regex=True).fillna('NA')
```

This is the example dataframe I have created:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
c= ('an', 'abc', 'pls')
data=['another','fan','Ind','abcd','point','plsea']    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns=['column']
```

This gives as output for `df`:

```
0       NA
1       NA
2      Ind
3       NA
4    point
5       NA
```

Comment: It is running with errors. But I am getting the same input as output without any change :(

Comment: I ran ur example. I am getting (another,fan, NA, abcd, point, plsea) as output. It is not working

Comment: What version of Python are you using, and what version of Pandas ? I have verified this on two different instances of Python 2.7 using Pandas version 0.18.0 and it gives the output I have included in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this pattern:

```
c= ('an', 'abc', 'pls')

df = ('another', 'fan', 'Ind', 'abcd', 'point', 'plsea')

for x in df:
    for y in c:
        print(y in x)
```