# Replacing values of an entire column via Python

Tags: python, replace

I'm working with a database of below size

```
data.shape
(18701954, 12)
```

One of the column in this database contains month description,

```
data.PERIOD_DESC.unique()
array(['Apr-19', 'May-19', 'Jun-19', 'Jul-19', 'Aug-19', 'Sep-19',
   'Oct-19', 'Nov-19', 'Dec-19', 'Jan-20', 'Feb-20', 'Mar-20',
   'Apr-20', 'May-20'], dtype=object)
```

I want to replace the column with "month description" to "numerical month" values and using the below code

```
data = data.replace(['Apr-19', 'May-19', 'Jun-19', 'Jul-19', 'Aug-19', 'Sep-19','Oct-19', 'Nov-19', 'Dec-19', 'Jan-20', 'Feb-20', 'Mar-20','Apr-20', 'May-20'],[201904, 201905, 201906, 201907, 201908, 201909, 201910,201911, 201912, 202001, 202002, 202003, 202004, 202005])
```

The existing code is taking considerable time. Is there any other way to complete this task differently (with lesser time).

I have considered the below link, but I think I'm already doing the suggested thing.
[Replace string/value in entire DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142304/replace-string-value-in-entire-dataframe)

Comment: Are you using numpy or pandas?

Comment: Hi Ann Zen, mainly pandas. But in the entire code I have used both.

Comment: What's your question about this?

Comment: Hi Nico, I have a code which is replacing the values and keeping the entire database, so it is doing the job, but taking several minutes to execute. However I'm wondering if there is an alternate way which may work faster and replace the desired values and keeps all the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do the replace operation only on your column of interest, as the `replace` operation currently walks through all your 12 columns:

```
data['PERIOD_DESC'] = data[['PERIOD_DESC']].replace(['Apr-19', 'May-19', 'Jun-19', 'Jul-19', 'Aug-19', 'Sep-19','Oct-19', 'Nov-19', 'Dec-19', 'Jan-20', 'Feb-20', 'Mar-20','Apr-20', 'May-20'],[201904, 201905, 201906, 201907, 201908, 201909, 201910,201911, 201912, 202001, 202002, 202003, 202004, 202005])
```

Comment: Hi, the resultant output has only the specific column, so can't use this. 
'raw_data.shape - (18701954, 1)'

Comment: I had still the `df` in the statement instead of `data`. This would only change one column in `data`, so invoking `data` should still have all the columns in there. Can you show the output?