# How to assign values to answers in a questionnaire in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a questionnaire with multiple answers choices like "nothing", "very little", "a bit", "partially", "a lot" "totally". To multiple questions.

I'm doing a correlation analysis (for start) on this and two other tests, with different but similar answers choices.

I'm trying to convert them to values with "weight" so that they matter on the calculations. Nothing(1), very little(2), totally(6) and etc...
Is it possible to do this in a way that will be permanent on the csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, without programming all of the words in before hand this would be impossible. But perhaps instead prompt the user to enter a number between 1 and 10. This would allow you to preform your correlation analysis more effectively.

However if would be possible to use a dictionary:

```
answer = input("Question: ")
answer_choices = {'Nothing':1, 'very little':2, 'totally':6}
if answer in answer_choices:
    number = answer_choices[answer]
else:
    raise ValueError
```

Comment: For clarification I'm working with pre-collected data and not building a questionnaire, so I already have a .csv with answers like 'Nothing' on cells and etc... Is there a way to substitute those answers with the numbers?

Comment: I've found the answer to my question on this post "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142304/replace-string-value-in-entire-dataframe".